# Populating another array from array - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Very simple thing I am trying to do in JS (assign the values of one array to another), but somehow the array `bar`'s value doesn't seem affected at all.

The first thing I tried, of course, was simply `bar = ar;` -- didn't work, so I tried manually looping through... still doesn't work.

I don't grok the quirks of Javascript! Please help!!

```
var ar=["apple","banana","canaple"];
var bar;
```

```
for(i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
    bar[i]=ar[i];
}
alert(ar[1]);
```

And, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vGycZ/

---

(The above is a simplification. The actual array is multidimensional.)

Comment: check this : http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_1/article_414-copy-or-clone-javascript-array-object

Comment: You could have spotted the syntax error ("arr" vs "ar") that was pointed out to you by using the Firebug plugin for Firefox. I'd go as far as to say you can't properly do Javascript development without it.

Comment: i don't do much javascript - and tbh i never figured out how to use Firebug :( ... point a few good tutorials at me?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you are not initializing `bar`:

```
var bar = [];
```

You also forgot to declare your `i` variable, which can be problematic, for example if the code is inside a function, `i` will end up being a global variable (always use `var` :).

But, you can avoid the loop, simply by using the [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/slice) method to create a copy of your first array:

```
var arr = ["apple","banana","canaple"];
var bar = arr.slice();
```

Comment: yes +1 for slice - btw does slice work for multidimensional arrays?

Comment: ina: it appears you can use a little trick for that! var bar = arr.concat();

Comment: @ina: `slice` will *shallow copy* the array elements that are objects, could you provide a less simplified example, to see exactly what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 9):

[copy-or-clone-javascript-array-object](http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_1/article_414-copy-or-clone-javascript-array-object)

```
var a = [ 'apple', 'orange', 'grape' ];
 b = a.slice(0);
```

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 8):

In ES6 you can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
var ar = ["apple","banana","canaple"];
var bar = Array.from(ar);
alert(bar[1]); // alerts 'banana'
```

Answer (score 4):

<s>You have two problems:</s>

First you need to initialize `bar` as an array:

```
var bar = [];
```

<s>Then `arr` should be `ar` in here:</s>

```
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
```

Then you'll get alerted your banana :)

Comment: yup - exactly it. too used to php sloppiness, forgot to declare the array! thanks for being the first to answer!

Answer (score 4):

With `ES6`+ you can simply do this

```
const original = [1, 2, 3];
const newArray = [...original];
```

The documentation for spread syntax is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

To check, run this small code on `dev console`

```js
const k = [1, 2];
const l = k
k === l
> true
const m = [...k]
m
> [1, 2]
k === m
> false
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation re: this.

Answer (score 2):

You have misspelled variable ar
Try this

```
for(i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
    bar[i]=ar[i];
}
alert(ar[1]);
```

Comment: yes ty for the pointer - this was not actual code, just brutal simplification typed up too quickly for a jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably here in the for loop statement:

```
for(i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
    bar[i]=ar[i];
}
alert(ar[1]);
```

You need to fix to `ar.length` instead of `arr.length.` And it's better to initialize bar as: `var bar = []`.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the variable `arr` in the for loop is not the same as your original array `ar`: you have one too many `r`.