# Why is that i can't inject the child component values into parent component?

Tags: angular

Hie...I am having a child component which has form.I am trying to inject the form values of child into parent. I am getting the control group but i am not able to get the values.I have made a plunker demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/I5feR6NHdQuTT7rJrVYA?p=preview

```
onSubmit(value) {
console.log(this.app.addressForm.value);
console.log('you submitted value: ', value);  
}
```

This is how i am getting the value of child form i have mentioned the providers in Parent component...Somebody please tell me how to get the form values of child component when something is entered into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After having a look at your plunkr, I see several possibilities here:

- You can directly reference child component like the `Address` one using the `ViewChild` annotation. See this answer [Angular2 : No provider for String! (child -> String) in [Array in parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148665/angular2-no-provider-for-string-child-string-in-array-in-parent/35148706#35148706)

  ```
  @Component({
    (...)
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild(Address)
    address:Address; // your app property
    (...)
  }
  ```

  You can use the `address` property when you click on the submit button to have access to the `addressForm` property of the `Address` component.
- Do you want to define and manage all controls within your `AppComponent`. If so it will be possible to pass them as parameter of your `Address` component. This way you will work by reference so your parent component will know the value when clicking on the submit button. Something like that:

  ```
  @Component({
    (...)
  })
  export class Address{
    @Input()
    address1Ctrl:Control;
    @Input()
    cityCtrl:Control;

    constructor() {
      // No need to configure controls here
    }
  }

  @Component({
    (...)
    template: `
      (...)
      <address [address1Ctrl]="myForm.controls.address1"
               [cityCtrl]="myForm.controls.address1"></address>
      (...)
    `
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {  
      this.myForm = fb.group({  
       'name':  ['', Validators.required],
       'address1':  new Control('',Validators.required),
       'city':new Control('',Validators.required)
       'Phone':  ['', Validators.required]
      });
  }
  ```
- The last option is to implement a `NgForm` / `NgControl` compliant component. It's a bit more advanced approach. See this answer for more details: [Angular 2 custom form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948961/angular-2-custom-form-input/34998780#34998780)

I refactored your plunkr with the first approach. See this new plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/sTEU4Fz7b7TXtRo1LXgK?p=preview.