# Angular 2 Children components detect changes in parent

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a component which displays a list of 'items' which are components created with a selector. I have a checkbox which i want, when clicked to update the 'state' of all child components.

Im really struggling to find the correct solution for doing this.
Please see [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OM7qR54UR9HRH0ZVToeT?p=preview) for more info.

```js
//our root app component
import {Component, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core'

class Item {
  name: boolean;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-item',
  template: `
    <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="state"/> {{state}}</label>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyItemComponent {
  state: boolean = false;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;">
      <label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="state"/> {{state}}</label>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="#item of items">
      <my-item></my-item>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [MyItemComponent]
})
export class App {
  state: boolean = true;
  items: Item[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.items.push(new Item("hello"));
    this.items.push(new Item("test"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-item',
  inputs: ['state']; // added
  template: `
    <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="state"/> {{state}}</label>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyItemComponent {
  state: boolean = false;
}
```

and then use it like

```ts
<my-item [state]="state"></my-item>
```

**original**

Angular change detection doesn't detect changes in arrays.
This should make it work:

```ts
  constructor() {
    this.items.push(new Item("hello"));
    this.items.push(new Item("test"));
    this.items = this.items.slice();
  }
```

This way a new array (a copy) is assigned to `this.items` and therefore Angular will recognize it as change.

In `MyItem` you need an `input`

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-item',
  inputs: ['items']; // added
  template: `
    <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="state"/> {{state}}</label>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyItemComponent {
  state: boolean = false;
  items: Item[]; // added
}
```

then you build the connection with

```ts
<my-item [items]="items"></my-item>
```

To get code called in `MyItemComponent` when `items` change implement `ngOnChanges()` See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnChanges-interface.html

```ts
export class MyItemComponent {
  state: boolean = false;
  items: Item[]; // added
  ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    console.log('ngOnChanges - myProp = ' + changes['items'].currentValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont need to detect changes in the array. I just need the child components to be able to detect changes to the parent 'state' boolean.

Comment: Then it's the same principle but you don't need the slice and the `ngOnChanges()`

Comment: ok, thanks for your input. I've sussed it now using the 'properties' of the Component.

Comment: `properties` is the deprecated predecessor of `inputs`.

Answer (score 3):

What @Günter said, it's completely true!

That said, I see some mistakes into your plunkr:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-item',
  template: `
    <div>Hello</div>
  `
});  // <------- Remove the ;
export class MyItemComponent {

}
```

And you missed the component in the `directives` property:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="state"/> {{state}}</label>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="#item of items">
      <my-item></my-item>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [] // <-------- Add the MyItemComponent component
})
export class App {
  (...)
}
```

**Edit**

You can leverage the `@ViewChildren` decorator to reference children directly.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    (...)
  `,
  directives: [MyItemComponent]
})
export class App {
  (...)
  @ViewChildren(MyItemComponent)
  children:MyItemComponent[];
  (...)
}
```

Then you can add a control to your checkbox to detect changes and update state of child components accordingly:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;">
      <label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="state"  
            [ngFormControl]="stateCtrl"/> {{state}}</label>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="#item of items">
      <my-item></my-item>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [MyItemComponent]
})
export class App {
  (...)
  constructor() {
    this.items.push(new Item("hello"));
    this.items.push(new Item("test"));

    this.stateCtrl = new Control();
    this.stateCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.children._results.forEach(child => {
          child.state = data;
        });
      });
  }
}
```

I updated your plunkr with this approach: https://plnkr.co/edit/nAA2VxZmWy0d4lljvPpU?p=preview.

See this link for more details: [Why is that i can't inject the child component values into parent component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227990/why-is-that-i-cant-inject-the-child-component-values-into-parent-component/35230219#35230219)

Comment: I think I forgot to save my final changes to the Plunkr before pasting the link. Please see updated now. Im not sure the solutions are what im trying to achieve. When i tick/untick the checkbox inside the red, i want both/all children to update their state also.

Comment: Oh! I forked and updated your plunkr with an approach based on the `@ViewChildren` decorator and form control. I updated my answer with its description...

Comment: Interesting approach, but it requires that the App component's logic stays in sync with the child component's template -- i.e., the App logic needs to know that the child component's template is using the `state` property.  This is very tight coupling, hence rather fragile.  It is better to use input properties, which act as a public API for the child component.  Another way to reduce coupling (with your approach) is to add a method to the child component which sets the internal `state` property.  Then the App component can call that public API method, rather than directly modify `state`.