# Angular2 @ViewChildren/@ViewQuery's QueryList not updated when dynamically adding second level children

Tags: angular

I want to make a directory tree and to have access to all items regardless of the level, but @ViewChildren/@ViewQuery's QueryList is not updated when I dynamically add second level children:

```js
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component, View, QueryList,ViewQuery, Query,ViewChildren} from 'angular2/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'item',
})
@View({
    template: `
        <button (click)="addChild()">Add Child</button>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
        <div *ngFor="#child of children; #i = index">
          <item> {{child.name}}</item>
        </div>
    `
})
export class Item {
    //public children = [ { name: 'Child 1', age: 22 } ];
    public children = [];
    addChild() {
        this.children.push({ name: 'Child' + (this.children.length + 1), age: 18 });
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
    directives: [Item],
    template: `
        <button (click)="addParent()">Add Parent</button>

        <div *ngFor="#user of users; #i = index">
          <item #item> {{user.name}}</item>
        </div>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
    public users = [
        { name: 'Parent 1', age: 22 }
    ];
    @ViewChildren(Item,  {descendants: true}) itemList: QueryList<Item>;
    constructor() {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.itemList);
        this.itemList.changes.subscribe(() => console.log(this.itemList));
    }

    addParent() {
        this.users.push({ name: 'Parent ' + (this.users.length + 1), age: 18 });
    }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

It is updated when I addParent(), but not updated when I addChild(). It looks like QueryList is subscribed only for top level changes. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

I think that it's something more general than the use of `@ViewChildren` / `@ViewQuery`.

In fact, it's the way Angular2 handles the change detection. I mean updates within objects don't trigger change detection but if you update the whole reference, it does.

So you need to refactor a bit your `removeDynamic` method:

```
addChild() {
  this.children.push({ name: 'Child' + (this.children.length + 1), age: 18 });
  this.children = this.children.slice();
}

addParent() {
  this.users.push({ name: 'Parent ' + (this.users.length + 1), age: 18 });
  this.users = this.users.slice();
}
```

See this answer regarding the use of the `slice` method:

- [Populating another array from array - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438027/populating-another-array-from-array-javascript)

Here is the answer from the Angular team regarding this behavior: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6458.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry